# SQL Select Statement - Column Ambiguously Defined even when defining which table each column comes from

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm doing a beginners course on SQL and databases, and I'm trying to write a select statement that will join two tables on Oracle Apex.  I'm using join...on... to do so.  The two tables each have a column named the same, with the columns filled with matching values.  Obviously, they tables need to join where the values match in each column.  Here's the code:

```
select TRANSACTION_ID, BUYER_ID, FIRST_NAME 
from TRANSACTIONS
join BUYER
on TRANSACTIONS.BUYER_ID = BUYER.BUYER_ID;
```

- The two Tables are named "TRANSACTIONS" and "BUYER".
- Both tables have a column named "BUYER_ID".
- Only the table "TRANSACTIONS" has a column named "LOT_ID", which is associated with the buyer ID
- Only the table "BUYER" has a column named "FIRST_NAME", which is associated with the buyer ID

So if I were to simply write,

```
on BUYER_ID = BUYER_ID;
```

as I understand that would return the error saying "Columns Ambiguously Defined".  But even when I specify the tables, as in,

```
on TRANSACTIONS.BUYER_ID = BUYER.BUYER_ID;
```

I still get a "Columns Ambiguously Defined".  I wondered if it was an issue with the two columns having to be presented with the same name, so I tried,

```
on TRANSACTIONS.BUYER_ID as "BUYER_ID1" = BUYER.BUYER_ID as "BUYER_ID2";
```

but then that returns "invalid relational operator".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't in the join, you also have to fully specify the column in the SELECT statement as well, or it won't know which of the BUYER_ID columns to display. Change it to SELECT BUYER.BUYER_ID and it will work.